# How to force Chrome to end session in Flask when closing the browser?

Tags: google-chrome, flask

I'm working on implementing sessions with Flask on Google App Engine and Chrome (Linux) is not ending the session when closing the browser. Firefox works OK.

**Chrome (Linux)**
I login, and unless I specifically logout the session is preserved by Chrome when I close the browser and start with a blank browser page. I can see that a cookie named localhost is created. Upon examination with Chrome, the cookie is indeed set to expire when the browser session closes.
I have changed the settings in Chrome to start with a new tab (not where it left off last time), yet the session is preserved.

**Firefox (Linux)**
Works as expected: I login to the app, close the browser and next time I open the browser I get the login screen.

Here's main.py:

```
from flask import Flask etc etc

# Import Blueprints
from login_bp import login_bp

app = Flask(__name__)

#Register Blueprints
app.register_blueprint(login_bp)

# Set the cookie secret key to some random bytes. Keep this really secret!
app.secret_key = b'_@%@@^)_*_)!!^%&*'

@app.route('/')
def main():
    if 'username' in session:
        session.permanent = False
        message = "This site is for development purposes only"
        return render_template('main.html', username=session['username'], message=message) 
    return redirect(url_for('login_bp.login'))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    # remove the username from the session if it's there
    session.pop('username', None)
    return redirect(url_for('login_bp.login'))
```

The login blueprint (login_bp.py):

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template
from flask import session, redirect, url_for, escape, request

login_bp = Blueprint('login_bp', __name__)

@login_bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def login():
    message = 'Some blurb' 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['username'] = request.form['username']
        session.permanent = False
        return redirect(url_for('main'))

    return render_template('login.html', message=message)
```

Any ideas how to force Chrome to end the session when closing the browser?

Thanks!